# Simple GUI for validating username and password

Tags: java

How can I complete the following code for validating a user name and password?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LibnValidation().setVisible(true);
            boolean result = validation();
            if(!result)
            {

            }
        }

        private boolean validation() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
            boolean valid = false;
            if(librarian.getText().equals("kani" && jPasswordField1.getPassword().equals("*****")){
                valid = true;
            }
            return valid;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: First, you probably should remove the throwing of a UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Also, you might want to run the validation code after the user enters in the username and password.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(librarian.getText().equals("kani" && jPasswordField1.getPassword().equals("*****")){
                valid = true;
}
```

This isn't proper code. make it

```
if(librarian.getText().equals("kani") && new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword()).equals("*****")) {
                valid = true;
}
```

**Note**:  I assume that you know that `*****` is the password , not the character being displayed over there.

Comment: In case anyone missed it (took me a minute to find the difference). There is a bracket missing after "kani".

Comment: also `getPassword()` returns `char[]`

Answer (score -1):

try this along with jigar joshi suggestion

```
boolean result=false;
result = validation();
if(!result)
{    
}
```

Comment: for being sure that validation method decide the result if it will be true or false..